# Is this the right way to set this up for selection in jquery

Tags: jquery

Is this the right way to select an element, it seems to work but looks really ugly code wise

```
$(this).parent().parent().siblings('.photoWrap');
```

Comment: Post more of your code and a better solution may present itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent's parent has a class you can identify it, you could use `.closests()` - You'd have less code then, it'd be up to you if that's less "ugly".

Answer (score 1):

If you truly only want elements with the class of `photoWrap` that are siblings of the parent of the parent of the current element...then yes, it's the right way.

Answer (score 1):

If it works, it is right. Hard to say more without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably call `.closest('selector')` to find the innermost parent that matches a selector instead of calling `.parent().parent()`.
This way, the code won't break if you add an intermediate parent.